# styling external widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website has an external widget that displays a table.

The widget comes with some inline CSS. Is there a way to remove this CSS before appending the widget to my page, so that only my css file rules will apply?

The markup looks like this:

```
<div id="widgetContainer">
    <script language='javascript' src='http://www.esake.gr/scripts/create_widget.php?pw=1&maw=242&fof=Verdana&tifs=14&tic=3A3A3A&tibc=FFFFFF&dafs=12&dac=3A3A3A&dabc=FFFFFF&ces=0&cep=1&langid=gr'></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using jQuery,

Assuming you'd have a parent container for your widget, you could do the following,

```
$("#parentContainer").children().removeAttr("style");
```

Just created a quick mockup here: http://jsfiddle.net/j3GPL/

Answer (score 1):

your best bet will be to override the css. e.g.

```
td { background: #f00!important;}
```

see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aKsXZ/) for an example.